# Issues dismissing keyboard conditionally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an app that has a username and password field. I want to validate the input before the the user is allowed to stop editing the field. To do that, I'm using the textFieldShouldEndEditing delegate method. If the input doesn't validate I display a UIAlertView.

This approach works as advertised - the user cannot leave the field if the input doesn't validate.

To have the done button on the keyboard dismiss the keyboard, I call resignFirstResponder on the textfield.

The issue I have is the alert is being called twice.  How do I keep the alert from showing twice?

*edit for clarification*

What is happening is that the alert appears, then another alert appears. I then have to dismiss both windows to fix the input.

Here is the textFieldShouldEndEditing method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"function called %@",textField);
    if([textField.text length] == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if(textField == userName)
    {
    if([self userNameValidated:textField.text])
    {
        NSLog(@"name validated");
        NSString *tempDonerName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(@"%@",userName.text)];
        //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tempDonerName forKey:@"name"];
        [tempDonerName release];
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"name did not validate");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Invalid Username",@"Invalid Username title")
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Please make sure there are no apostrophes,spaces in the username, and that the username is less than 12 characters",@"Invalid username message")
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"OK Text") 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];            

        return NO;
    }

} else if (textField == userPin) {
    if([self userPinValidated:textField.text])
    {
        NSLog(@"pin validated");
        //NSString *tempDonerPin = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(@"%@",userPin.text)];              
        //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tempDonerPin forKey:@"pin"];
        //[tempDonerPin release];
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"pin did not validate");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Invalid Password",@"Invalid Pin title")
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Please make sure there are no apostrophes in the password",@"Invalid password message")
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"OK Text") 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        return NO;
    }
}else {
    NSLog(@"code validate - shouldn't get called");
    return YES;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: Do you mean that the alert shows up twice after the user presses the done button once? Or that the user has to press the done button two (or three?) times before the name is validated? It seems like you are handling the strings a bit strangely so it could have something to do with that. Or perhaps the problem is in your validation method. Hard to tell from this.

Comment: This won't help you solve your problem, but you could make your code a lot more modular -- and readable/self-documenting -- by using the UITextField's "tag" field to specify which field is which, and then using a switch statement for each possible tag.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the double alert: resignFirstResponder is going to call textFieldShouldEndEditing, there's no way around that.  So you need either to pass a flag saying that it's cool to exit the field with unvalidated input, or otherwise clear the content; or make it a user decision and enable the clear button on the field.

Comment: I was afraid of that. What I'm going to try is to only show an alert if one is not currently visible.